# How to get image into div completely without it spilling over the side?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to make a horizontal card across part of the screen and so far everything looks exactly the way I want except the image only display partially in the card border, about halfway, and the covers the next card. I am trying to get it to sit evenly within the card. I have included a photo of what I mean and this is the code I am using. Please let me know if you need to see the html.

Edit: I added the html

[image: photo spilling onto next div]

```
.cardcontainer {
    border: white solid 1px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(7, 16, 31);
}

.cardheading {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.cardpara {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    width: auto;
}

.cardimg {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    float: right;
    padding:0;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.learnmorebutton {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: fade 10s linear infinite alternate;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="cardcontainer">
                    <h1 class="cardheading">placeholder<i class="location">placeholder</i></h1>
                    <p class="cardpara">placeholder</p>
                    <a class="learnmorebutton" href="#" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
                    <img class="cardimg" src="#">
                </div>
```

Comment: We definitely want to see the `HTML` :)

Comment: This all depends on the layout you are expecting once the `<img>` is in the proper place. But the reason for this is your `float: right` on the `.cardimg` element. You need to clear that float with `overflow: ?` on `.cardcontainer`. But I have a feeling you also want the image parallel with `<p>` so more needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to your question, is that you need to clear the float on the image by adding the `overflow` property to the parent. However, the content within `.cardpara` is going to push the image down. Not sure if that's what you want.

If you want the image next to the content in `<p>` and text to wrap around it, then move your `<img>` tag *before* `<p>` in the markup.

```css
.cardcontainer {
    border: white solid 1px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(7, 16, 31);
    overflow: auto;
}

.cardheading {
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.cardpara {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(117, 117, 117);
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-style: italic;
    width: auto;
}

.cardimg {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    float: right;
    padding:0;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.learnmorebutton {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    animation: fade 10s linear infinite alternate;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
  <h1 class="cardheading">placeholder<i class="location">placeholder</i></h1>
  <p class="cardpara">placeholder</p>
  <a class="learnmorebutton" href="#" target="_blank">Learn More</a>
  <img class="cardimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/130?text=PLACEHOLDER">
</div>
```

Comment: This work for getting the div around the image, so thank you for that, however it still isn't parallel to <p>. It is much better now though so thank you

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it, I used `overflow:auto` then I put the `<img>` before the `<p>` and changed it to the `<span>` element, then played around with the padding and line breaks and managed to get my resault. Thanks EternalHour :)

Comment: No need to create an answer. Please delete your answer and add it as a comment then accept mine.